# Python: Detecting and parametrizing simple rectangular / Gaussian stripe patterns in image matrices

Tags: python, image, image-processing, matrix, shapes

I am looking for a good solution to detect and describe rectangular shaped patterns in a (noisy) matrix image.
An example is given below:

[image: Pattern]

The image is monochromatic, the colors are just indicating the value of a pixel.

How can I detect these rectangular shapes and save them in a parametrized manner?
So far I havent tried anything, but my way forward would be to detect the edges by detecting value differences over a threshold inside certain areas.

Comment: Your question is very vague! What have you tried? Are they always the same colour? Is the background always the same colour? Are they always vertical stripes or is their orientation random? Are they of a known, fixed size? Are there always two? Are they always parallel?

Comment: Sorry, I will clarify a little: The image is monochromatic (the pixels just have a certain value - which is depicted by the color). The orientatation is always the same and the length is known. There can be more than 2. They are alwys parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did this in the command-line with **ImageMagick** but you can do just the same thing in Python with [wand](https://pypi.org/project/Wand/) which is based on **ImageMagick** or with **OpenCV** using template matching.

Basically, the shape you are looking for is 7x106 pixels. So, I made a black bar exactly that shape and asked **ImageMagick** to look in a greyscale copy of your image for the best location that most nearly matches such a solid black bar:

Make black bar:

```
magick -size 7x106 xc:black png8:bar.png
```

Make your image greyscale:

```
magick stripes.png -colorspace gray gstripe.png
```

Search for best black bar in image:

```
magick compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -metric RMSE -subimage-search gstripe.png bar.png r.png
24655.4 (0.376218) @ 33,29
```

That gives this output:

[image]

The `33,29` tells me the top-left of the bar. So, I now draw a white rectangle there to hide the first bar and seek the second:

```
magick gstripe.png -fill white -draw "rectangle 33,29 40,135" gstripe2.png

magick compare -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -metric RMSE -subimage-search gstripe2.png bar.png r.png
30287.3 (0.462155) @ 162,32
```

And that tells me the second bar is at coordinates `162,32`:

[image]

---

Another method is to use Numpy to calculate the mean of all the columns in your image and then look for the dark areas:

```
columnMeans = np.mean(im, axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer! I just installed wand. I still have to install ImageMagick , which seems quite complicated in windows. Does this solution also work for varying widths of the stripes?

Comment: That was why I asked if the bars were a fixed, known size in the comments. You could iterate over different widths if you wanted to - it depends on your images but I have only seen one so I cannot be sure what to expect or how much variation there is.

Comment: I think your second idea with np.mean sounds promising. I will try it out!

Comment: which libary did you use to import the png file?

Comment: PIL/Pillow, but you can use OpenCV `imread()` or `wand` or `pyvips` or `scikit-image`.